# Keras conv2d input shape error

Tags: python-3.x, keras, convolution, mnist

Unable to solve the issue with keras input shape error. How to actually specify dimensions in the conv2d layer is unknown. Tried different methods, still couldn't get it to work. Below mentioned is the code where I tried to implement a conv net using keras for a mnist dataset. The array initially was 1x784. But I reshaped it to 28x28 and it still didn't work. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks !

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 20
number_of_classes = 10

def build_brain():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def shared_dataset(data_xy):
    data_x, data_y = data_xy
    shared_x = np.asarray(data_x)
    shared_y = np.asarray(data_y)
    return shared_x, shared_y

f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f,encoding='latin1')
f.close()

test_set_x, test_set_y = shared_dataset(test_set)
valid_set_x, valid_set_y = shared_dataset(valid_set)
train_set_x, train_set_y = shared_dataset(train_set)


train_set_x = train_set_x.reshape(-1,28,28)
valid_set_x = valid_set_x.reshape(-1,28,28)
test_set_x = test_set_x.reshape(-1,28,28)


brain = build_brain()
asd = brain.fit(train_set_x, train_set_y, epochs=30, validation_data = (valid_set_x, valid_set_y), batch_size=32)
score = brain.evaluate(test_set_x, test_set_y, batch_size = 32)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
train_set_x = train_set_x.reshape(-1,28,28)
valid_set_x = valid_set_x.reshape(-1,28,28)
test_set_x = test_set_x.reshape(-1,28,28)
```

The network expects training inputs with shape (samples, 28, 28, 1), as you used input_shape = (28, 28, 1). So the correct reshapes are:

```
train_set_x = train_set_x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
valid_set_x = valid_set_x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
test_set_x = test_set_x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
```